# Find $0 \le x \le 1$ that maximizes $k$ in $Ax = kb$ as linear program?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, linear-programming

Please consider the following optimization problem:

Find any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that maximizes $k \in \mathbb{R}$, given a constant $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrix and constant $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ vector and under the constraints:

$$Ax = kb \\
0 \le x_i \le 1$$

I've observed the following things about the problem:

- There is always at least one solution because when $x = \vec0$ then $k = 0$.
- As when $x = \vec0$, $k = 0$, so in every solution $k \ge 0$
- You could normalize $b$ to a unit vector fairly trivially if needed, by substituting $\frac{k}{\Vert b \Vert}$
- We could look at this geometrically by imagining the image of the unit hypercube (positioned with coordinates from 0 to 1) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the linear transform $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, intersecting that with the line spanned by $b$ and then finding the end point of the resulting line segment that is farthest from origin.

Can this optimization problem be reformulated as a linear programming problem in standard form?  If so, how?

If not, how would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this as a linear program where the variables are $(x,k)$, with $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$, and $Ax - kb = [A |-b](x,k)^T = 0$ and the objective function is $k$.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos There are a number of different standard forms that are (mostly) equivalent. Another common one is $Ax = b, x \geq 0$ (sometimes called equational form). The one I wrote is like $Ax = b$ with some non-negativity constraints and some unconstrained variables. This is not quite equivalent to the other ones since it allows you to have lines in your feasible set. However, since you know that $k \geq 0$ because of the $x = 0$ solution, you could add the constraint $k \geq 0$ without any loss and put it in equational form.